# How to play button tap sound while recording audio?

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudiosession

I'm trying to play a button tap sound when I start recording a audio.Is it possible to play back a sound while it is recording it, live?.

**Requirements:**

1) if i tap on record button don't want to start recording after completion of record button tap sound.it takes time delay.

2) if i tap on record button don't want to record beef sound to recorded audio file.

3) I want play button tap sound and record audio simultaneously without overlapping.

**start Recording:**

```
-(IBAction)btnRecordTap:(id)sender
{
[self playTapSound:@"press.wav"];

// Set the audio file
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                           @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                           nil];
NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

// Setup audio session
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

// Define the recorder setting
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

// Initiate and prepare the recorder
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
recorder.delegate = self;
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder prepareToRecord];
}
```

**play System sound**

```
//---------------play button sound--------------------

 -(SystemSoundID) playASound: (NSString *) fileName
 {
//Get the filename of the sound file:
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                  fileName];

//Get a URL for the sound file
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)filePath, &soundFileObject);

//play the file
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundFileObject);
return soundFileObject;
}

-(void)playTapSound:(NSString *)file
{
 SystemSoundID id = [self playASound:file];
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (id,NULL,NULL,completionCallback,(__bridge_retained void *)self);
}

static void completionCallback (SystemSoundID  ssID,void *clientData)
{
    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion (ssID);
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(ssID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to play tap sound in background thread:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(PlayTapSound:) withObject:nil];
// Start recording
    .
    .

-(void)PlayTapSound
{
     // play tap sound code.
}
```

Play sound directly before recording. Like after prepareToRecord.